# New in 4.7.4: QDir::homePath() gives out empty string

Tags: qt

```
QString path = QDir::homePath();  // <-- "path" is always ""
```

Is this a new bug in 4.7.4? use to work well in 4.7.3

I’m on OSX Lion (4.7.3 worked on Lion well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “Clear System Environment” probably cleared the `HOME` environment variable too.

Basically, `QDir::homePath()` returns `QFile::decodeName(QByteArray(::getenv("HOME")))` almost unchecked. And that's an empty string, if there is no `HOME` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm It seems the problem is resolved if I don’t use the “Clear System Environment”. I unchecked it, then re-built and it worked fine. could it be the “SHELL” definitions? I can’t think of anything other than that that’s remotely related to this. I guess something caused Qt to have **QT_NO_FSFILEENGINE** defined and thus to return an empty string:

```
// from Qt source file: QDir.cpp

QString QDirPrivate()
{
#ifdef QT_NO_FSFILEENGINE
    return QString();
#else
    return cleanPath(QFSFileEngine::homePath());
#endif
}
```